# How to format PowerShell results from ForEach

Tags: powershell, reporting, powershell-4.0

I am trying to get complete a request of amount of files in a directory and then the total size of that directory. I've come up with this:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Users\$USERNAME%\Documents\list.txt |
    Foreach-Object {
        cd $_
        Write-Host $_ 
        (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Measure-Object).Count 
        (ls -r|measure -sum Length).Sum
    }
```

The txt file has contents such as:

```
\\directory\on\network\1
\\directory\on\network\also
```

Ultimately I need this in a spreadsheet, but I am failing with formatting. As is, it outputs straight to powershell, so with thousands of directories this isn't ideal. I've tried exporting to CSV but it overwrites the CSV with each result, and when I tried setting the function equal to a variable array and then exporting that, it simply output a blank file.

Any assistance with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to export to CSV you will need an object with properties. Your code generates a few values without any structure. Surely the `%` in your sample code is a typo, it definitely doesn't belong there. It is generally considered bad practice to use aliases in scripts, however you should, at a minimum, keep it consistent. One line you use `Get-ChildItem/Measure-Object` and the next use `ls/measure`. Regardless you don't show your export, so it's hard to help with what we can't see. You also don't need to `CD` into the directory, it seems it would only slow the script down if anything.

The easiest way I know to create an object is to use the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator.

```
$infile = "C:\Users\$USERNAME\Documents\list.txt"
$outfile = "C:\some\path\to.csv"

Get-Content -Path $infile |
    Foreach-Object {
        Write-Host Processing $_
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Path  = $_
            Total = (Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -File | Measure-Object).Count 
            Size  = (Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -File | Measure-Object -sum Length).Sum
        }
    } | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Edit

We should've ran the `Get-Childitem` call once and then pulled the info out. The first option is in "pipeline" mode can save on memory usage but might be slower. The second puts it all in memory first so it can be much quicker if it's not too large.

```
Get-Content -Path $infile |
    Foreach-Object {
        Write-Host Processing $_
        $files = Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -File | Measure-Object -sum Length
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Path  = $_
            Total = $files.Count 
            Size  = $files.Sum
        }
    } | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

or

```
$results = foreach($folder in Get-Content -Path $infile)
{
    Write-Host Processing $folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -File | Measure-Object -sum Length
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Path  = $folder
        Total = $files.Count 
        Size  = $files.Sum
    }
}
    
$results | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks Doug. This is very helpful. I am coming from a batch/cmd background and still learning a lot with powershell. Definitely crossing some wires occasionally with my code.

Comment: Running into issues with directories that are too long. I was trying to map each result to a temp drive then run the PSCustomObject functions against that temporary location. Seems kind of slow though. Do you know of another way?

Comment: Why do you think it's the PSCustomObject that is slow? It's most likely get-childitem -recurse that is slow. Can you show your code?

Comment: Check the edit, either of those should perform better since it's not doing the work twice.

Answer (score 0):

The -append flag in Export-Csv allows you to add to an existing file rather than overwriting.